# Matlab x-axis scaling – evenly spaced custom axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Using the variables below, I need to plot data (x_values, y_values) on an x axis with ticks at ‘x_labels’ values.  Each ‘x_labels’ tick must be evenly spaced on the x-axis (e.g. 1 cm).

I have been playing with 'XTick' and 'XTickLabel' variables and although I searched online all other examples are related to when the ‘x_labels’ and ‘x_values’ are identical.  The challenge here is that there is different spacing between ‘x_labels’ and ‘x_values’.  Please help!

```
x_labels = [4 8 16 32 64 128];
x_values = [5 10 35 50 60 70 90 120];
y_values = rand(1,length(x_values))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`set`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/set.html) command you can specify the [`xTick` and `xTickLabel`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) (near the bottom of the link) properties of the axis separately, xTick defines the tick marks locations and xTickLabel defines the labels.
So after plotting the data:

```
plot(x_values,y_values);
```

we can freely set the locations, in this example they are spaced evenly between zero and the max of `x_values`. The `set` command is then be used to set the axis properties, ([`gca`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) is the current axis handle)

```
x_label_locations = linspace(0,max(x_values),numel(x_labels));

set(gca,'xTick',x_label_locations,'xTickLabel',x_labels)
```